# Multi-upload images by html5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can multi-upload images by `html5` and `js` and `php`, Please give me a demo or example?

**Without using a plugin**

I try as this code in html and selected multi image:

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple">
```

But i give in php code just one image:

```
foreach( $_FILES['upload'] as $key => $all ){
            foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
                $new[$i][$key] = $val;    
            }    
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($new);
```

What do i do?

Comment: You want a code sample? This is not a question.

Comment: If you google "html5 multiple file upload", you get many examples like the following: http://css.dzone.com/articles/working-html5s-multiple-file http://css.dzone.com/articles/working-html5s-multiple-file

Comment: I just checked and the two examples above don't use a plugin.

Comment: I try and selected multi image in input file, but in php code i see just one from image selected, ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is a really good file uploader

Answer (score 1):

File upload with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars and preview images.
[File Upload Example](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)